# VS 2013, stop JQuery from trying to update to 2.x

Tags: jquery, visual-studio-2013, nuget

I manually installed jQuery 1.11 and edited the packages.config files to add the `allowedVersions` to try and prevent jQuery from updating to 2.x but when I check the updates section of the nugget GUI it is still listing the 2.x branch as an update. How can I stop that as I don't want to accidently update to 2.x and potentially break my site. My package.config contains this line for jQuery:

`<package id="jQuery" version="1.11.0" allowedVersions="[1,2]" targetFramework="net451" />`

and was based off of http://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/versioning

Also, is there some way to get nugget to notify me if a new 1.X package comes out?

Comment: @Jasen - I don't see any intent in the question of doing a blind update, quite the opposite in fact?

Comment: @Jasen Not sure what your talking about here about a blind update. I want to get notified if a new 1.x package comes out (like when 1.12 is released) so I can update the package and test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the version spec `[1,2)`, which loosely translated restricts version selection to `1 <= v < 2`

```
<package id="jQuery" version="1.11.0" targetFramework="net40" allowedVersions="[1,2)" />
```

I've tested that locally and works fine (NuGet 2.8.50126.400), in both Console and GUI.

Comment: Looks like a type-o in my code, I did not notice the ending of the `allowedVersions` is a ) instead of a ]. I will update and test tonight but it looks like that will fix it.

Comment: This has worked, kind of. It will no longer list the jQuery 2.x package if I try to manage the nugget packages of that one project, but if I try to manage it at the solution level it still appears. I am not able to locate a packages.config for the solution level. Do you know where/what file to update so it is filtered at the solution level?